# javascript array push empty keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating an apps that will loop all necessary field and store as object and pass it to backend via http.

I am using array push to add it to the object while looping.

Here is the code in JS.

**JS**

```
var form_data_body = [];
for (var k = 0; k < $scope.Tablelist.length; k++) {
  if ($scope.Tablelist[k].selected == true) {
    if ($scope.Tablelist[k].approve == "Y") {
      var Suppno = $scope.Tablelist[k].supp_no;
      var Price = $scope.Tablelist[k].unit_price;
      if (Suppno != "") {
        if (suppliersebelum == "") {
          suppliersebelum = Suppno;
        } else {
          if (suppliersebelum != Suppno) {
            continue;
          }
        }
        if (Price > 0) {
          var Matcode = $scope.Tablelist[k].matcode;
          var Poqty = $scope.Tablelist[k].pr_qty;
          var Prprice = $scope.Tablelist[k].unit_price;
          var Priceid = $scope.Tablelist[k].price_id;
          var Dept = $scope.Tablelist[k].req_dept;
          var Refno = $scope.Tablelist[k].reff;
          var ReqDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.Tablelist[k].date_req), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
          var Tanggal = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
          console.log(k);
          form_data_body.push = {
            matcode: Matcode, po_qty: Poqty, unit_price: Prprice, etd_date: ReqDate, dept_no: Dept,
            priceid: Priceid, ref_no: Refno
          };
        }
      } else {
        console.log("failed");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("failed");
    }
  }
}
console.log(Object.keys(form_data_body).length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(form_data_body));
```

Those code above will be fired when i click on button and will be through a tablelist, however no matter how much it meet the conditions, the `onsole.log(Object.keys(form_data_body).length);` will show `1` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(form_data_body));` will show `[]` and `console.log(k);` will show number of looping.

is there something wrong with the code that caused it cannot push to the `form_data_body` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
  form_data_body.push = {
        matcode: Matcode, po_qty: Poqty, unit_price: Prprice, etd_date: ReqDate, dept_no: Dept,
        priceid: Priceid, ref_no: Refno
      };
```

with

```
    form_data_body.push ( {
        matcode: Matcode, po_qty: Poqty, unit_price: Prprice, etd_date: ReqDate, dept_no: Dept,
        priceid: Priceid, ref_no: Refno
      });
```

Push is a method which takes item as parameter rather than assignment.

Comment: aha, thanks for point me out that line, i am searching for almost half a day but cant find that. thanks mate.

Comment: @JosephGoh glad to help